# DCG : zero-or-more, zero-or-one , one-or-more occurrences?

Tags: prolog, repeat, dcg

In DCG how do you implement : zero-or-more, zero-or-one , one-or-more occurrences ?

I'm talking about the following in pseudo code :

```
  sentence --> word+
  float --> int+, ['.'], int+
  nilORa --> a? 
  nilORaaaa --> a*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the or-nondeterminism offered by the clause set of a predicate (or, in this case, the set of DCG productions for the same DCG "nonterminal" - the DCG production is an alternative notation for a Horn clause)

Move the production that should be performed first to the top. For example, to collects at least one `word`, but possibly more, greedily:

```
sentence --> word, sentence.
sentence --> word.
```

Depending on how much determinism is in the grammar, you can even cut:

```
sentence --> word, !, sentence.
sentence --> word.
```

Same with a float. `digits` is at least one digit. There already is a definition for `digit` in the library I think:

```
float --> digits, ['.'], digits.

digits --> digit, digits.
digits --> digit.
```

`nilORa` is an `a` -- or possibly nothing:

```
nilORa --> a.
nilORa --> [].
```

`nilORaaaa` is an `a` followed by `nilORaaaa` -- or possibly nothing:

```
nilORaaaa --> a, nilORaaaa.
nilORaaaa --> [].
```

You should also be able to deploy `;` I think:

```
nilORaaaa --> (a, nilORaaa) ; [].
```

Comment: `?- phrase(nilORaaaa, List).
ERROR: Out of local stack`
We really shouldn't teach beginners to use inferior clause ordering.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie You are right about the teaching thing but how the hell do you go out of stack with this clause ordering???

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Ah I see, when you want to enumerate and `List` is still a var. I never read DCGs in the way of "enumerative generation".

Comment: It's a good habit to get into, since you get "testing for free" just like with non-DCG definitions. In general, recursive-clause-before-nonrecursive-clause is a big red flag for testability and composability (think generate-and-test patterns), unfortunately it's common in old, even otherwise very good, Prolog books. Also, for whatever it's worth, `[] ; (a, nilOraaaa)` is closer to the informal definition of "0 or more `a`s".

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie Thank you. I see. But won't the analysis/parsing process be much slower as it will traverse the grammar until it hits the failure condition of phrase/2, which is "no characters shall remain" and all the characters are still there? In fact, the parsing process changes from "cautiously succeed" (and maybe cut) to "aggressively fail" (and don't cut), so to say.  (Maybe one should load the branches with probabilities-of-being-selected )

Comment: On SWI `as2 --> [] | [a], as2.` is slightly faster than `as4 --> [a], as2 | [].` without optimization. With optimization the latter is very very slightly faster. `as1 --> []. as1 --> [a], as1.` is about 20% slower but is the only variant that doesn't leave a choice point when parsing a proper list. `as3 --> [a], as3. as3 --> [].` is almost 2x slower than the fastest variant. I benchmarked with `?- length(As, 1_000_000), maplist(=(a), As), time( (between(1, 100, _), phrase(as4, As), false) ).` Not all of these results make sense to me.